# Load Magento Layered Navigtion , After page loads

Tags: magento-1.6, layered-navigation, loadbalancing

I have some `heavy developments on my Left Hand Layered Navigation` , in Category View Page.So its `taking time to load , and increasing the page load time`.

I have **already  done code optimization**  and **rest of my code is not possible to remove from layered navigation** because of **client requirement.**.

So I want `to do some thing like this first load all products list then load  layered navigation but note it should not increase page load time`

So If it is possible anyhow that , I can load the navigation after page load  then It will be very good for me.

**Please help  me  and give me some suggestion**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Layered navigation block does 2 things:

1. it builds the left filters
2. it adds SQL conditions to the product collection.

So you have to load the navigation first, then the product collection.  Otherwise you'll always show all products in a category.

The solution is to split building left filters block and generating conditions for the product collection.

It allows you to load Mage_Catalog_Layere_View block via, say, AJAX call
after the page load.

Comment: how can we do this.can you give some solution?

Comment: Can you give me solution for same?